# How to pass variable (username) from URL to views?

Tags: django, view

I'm having a little confusion understanding how to pull the username from the url.  Here is my views.

VIEWS

```
def profile_listview(request, username,
    template_name=userena_settings.USERENA_PROFILE_DETAIL_TEMPLATE,
    extra_context=None, **kwargs):
    user = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(),
                             username__iexact=username)
    fullsalelist = Entry.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=username)
    userreviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name__username__iexact=username).order_by('-pub_date')

    if username == request.user.username:
        print request.user.username
        print username
        pageowner=True
        print "true"
```

URL

```
(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\@\.\w-]+)/listview/$', profile_listview),
```

fullsalelist and userreviews are all filtering objects by username which is the username in the URL (NOT the currently logged in user)

however, in the example below, both print statements print the same thing (which it shouldn't because I am logged in with one user and viewing the profile of another)

```
if username==request.user.username:
    print request.user.username  \\prints benjamin
    print username    \\prints benjamin, but I want it to print steve which is the username in the current profile URL
    pageowner=True
```

request.user.username and username print the same thing, which is the currently logged in user and NOT the username in the URL.  I'm confused why the example below correctly filters objects by the username in the URL, yet printing username will instead print the currently logged in user.

```
fullsalelist = Entry.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=username)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: is 'username' coming from (request, username) coming from the url username?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

Even though the URL bar in my browser showed /accounts/steve/listview

My AJAX code was actually sending a POST request /accounts/benjamin/listview

Oddly this did not negatively affect the intended functionality in anyway, but what it did do was make both 'username' and 'request.user.username' = benjamin, which confused the hell out of me.

Posting this in case it helps anyone else in the future.